# How to conditionally insert into mariadb based on if the entry already exists

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following:

Table with ID, title, userid

At the moment I have logic that when a certain media is viewed it is entered into the database in order to store view history.

Now, I am trying to prevent duplicate entries from being inserted. This is the code that I have tried and it is still duplicating entries.

```
    dataAccessor.viewers = {
  add: ({ courseId, viewerOid }) => {
    const query =
      "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM course_video_viewers WHERE course_id = ? AND WHERE azure_oid = ?) INSERT INTO course_video_viewers (course_id, azure_oid) VALUES (?, ?)";

    const inputs = [courseId, viewerOid];

    return sendQueryAndReturnResultsAsPromise(query, inputs);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to add a unique constraint in the table for the combination of the columns `course_id` and `azure_oid`:

```
ALTER TABLE course_video_viewers 
ADD CONSTRAINT un_con_video_view 
UNIQUE (course_id, azure_oid);
```

If you can't alter the table's definition you can use a `INSERT ... SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO course_video_viewers (course_id, azure_oid) 
SELECT ?, ?
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM course_video_viewers WHERE course_id = ? AND WHERE azure_oid = ?)
```

You may omit `FROM dual` if your version of MySql is 5.7+.

Comment: So this worked however I am now getting the following error: SqlError: Error in results, duplicate field name `id`.

Comment: @lhuf As you can see there is no `id` column in my code. I don't know how you execute it.

Comment: it was the first solution by the way... the id is our unique key

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should have a unique index on `course_id,azure_oid` That would prevent duplicates from being inserted. Then you can run `insert ignore into course_video_viewers...` and it will internally drop the record if it exists and reinsert it.